# Как можно узнать версию MySQL

Tags: mysql

Как можно узнать версию MySQL под Windows?

Comment: Посмотреть свойства файла, который запускается при старте службы.

Comment: помог ответ????

Answer (score 1):

вот команда ее запускают в терминале MySql

```
mysql -V
```

Comment: это, как ни странно, клиент

Answer (score 1):

1. Открываем **MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client**
2. Вводим пароль **root**'a
3. Пишем **\s** и жмём Enter
4. В ответе ищем строку **Server Version**

[image: Server Version]

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего:

```
SELECT VERSION()
```

либо:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем мудрить: в консоле cmd: `[путь]mysql.exe --version`
Или из каталога bin, где лежит сам файл mysql.exe, тогда можно просто `mysql.exe --version`